# How can I detect mobile device only in VB.Net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Tried with IsMobileDevice method and for tablet it's also giving true. 
Tried with Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth and it gives always gives 640.

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Is a tablet not mobile? Pretty sure I can carry all my tablets with me.. And when I play 20Q while thinking of an iPad I answer "yes" to "Is it something you bring along?" :)

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I want to identity whether the request is coming from mobile or tablet or desktop. Tried with Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice method but it's identifying mobile and tablet both at the same time. How can I seperate these two?

Comment: Why would you just repeat what you'd already posted? It's obvious that we already know that. I'm asking you WHY?!